# create a footer for only one page on a site collection?

Tags: footer

I just wanted to have a horizontal bar with words at the bottom of the home page of the site collection..
How will I be able to do this? I didn't want to do it on the masterpages.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't wanna use SPD, you can do it with some jQuery in a text file and connect it to a content editor webpart on the page.

```
<script src="../SiteAssets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="Footer" class="s4-notdlg" style="background:black;color:white">This is a footer</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#s4-workspace" ).append( $( "#Footer" ) );
});
</script>
```

I would then recommend to style the div "Footer" by using CSS instead as i did directly in the HTML.

[image]

Comment: Do I need to put use/put this in the cEwP?
<script src="../SiteAssets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @PradeepKumar Yes, you will need to download a jquery library and store locally or use a jQuery from a CDN. Just grab the latest version and add to a library on the same site. http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: https://sgryphon.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/ways-to-load-jquery-in-sharepoint-20102013/

Answer (score 1):

Edit the page in SharePoint Designer, and you can add any style you want inline, since it should affect only one page.